# Side by side dual bar chart with Chart.js 2

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

[image]

Is it possible to do this with Chart.js (v2)? I know how to do multiple axes charts, but all of the examples I've seen so far are limited to overlapped (eg:line+bar) or stacked bar charts that are on the same plane.
[This is a close example of what I want but not quite right](https://jsfiddle.net/vjt2r1mL/644/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('chart');
new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Target', 'Actual'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'A',
      yAxisID: 'A',
      data: [1400,0]
    }, {
      label: 'B',
      yAxisID: 'B',
      data: [0,0.83]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        id: 'A',
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'left',
      }, {
        id: 'B',
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'right',
        ticks: {
          max: 1,
          min: 0
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not quite right about it?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf because I'm actually showing zero in the first axis [val, 0] and [0, val] as a bottom anchor so that it seems as if theyre two separate axes shown side by side when they're just overlapping but with a 0 instead on each. This makes the chart show an obvious gap in the center because theyre showing the 0 value. Changing the chart type to 'line' shows this.